# Why does React Native Navigation listener trigger on the first try?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, addeventlistener

I want to have an event listener that triggers an event when a user arrives on a screen.  The event, in this case, is to attempt to retrieve a token and, if none exists, open a modal.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the listener does not trigger any events on the first time the user arrives on the screen, but only on the second time.  On the first time, the `useEffect` doesn't run to show "Listener is run" nor does it retrieve the token.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const focusListener = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
            console.log("Listener is run")
            retrieveToken()
        })

        return () => {
           focusListener.remove()
        }
    }, [])

    const retrieveToken = async () => {
        try {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(LOGIN_TOKEN)
            console.log("token", token)
            if(!token) {
                console.log("Modal is run")
                authModalOpen()
            }
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(err)
        }
    }
```

I've tried changing `didFocus` to `willFocus`, but still doesn't work.

Comment: why don't u put a check on componentdidmount and each time they come to that screen, check if token present or not and based on that run your modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6183), a solution is to use `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`.

The reason is that `useEffect` will run after the component renders and the browser has already painted those changes. I guess at that time it is too late for the listener. `useLayoutEffect` on the other hand, runs before the browser paints the changes from the render.